# Moving from one UIViewController to another in Swift programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 ViewControllers. I don't have a storyboard. I want to move from the first view to another once everything is done in first viewController. What is the way to do it? It is something like this, the first view shows an image and in the background makes some API calls. After API call succeeds, I want it to move to the second ViewController(`LoginActivityViewController`). I tried calling this in the first ViewController:

```
var loginActivity = LoginActivityViewController()
self.navigationController.pushViewController(loginActivity, animated: true)
```

But, this did not work. How to do this?

Here is my application function in AppDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let navigationController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: RootViewController())
    navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    window!.rootViewController = navigationController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Here is my RootViewController's viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let image1 = UIImage(named: "Default.png")
    let imageview = UIImageView(image: image1)
    self.view.addSubview(imageview)
    var loginActivity = LoginActivityViewController()
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(loginActivity, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: do you have a valid navigation controller instance in the view hierarchy?

Comment: I depends what you mean between 'move'?

Comment: I created an instance. But that too does not work. I want to perform a segue.

Comment: @Rishi, tell us the procedure how your code creates the view hierarchy exactly. you are messing up something, but the current information is not enough to tell where.

Comment: @Rishi, you just said you created a navigation controller, but in your posted code there is _zero_ navigation controller has been created.

Answer (score 2):

this how your method should look with initing a navigation controller properly:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let rootViewController: RootViewController = RootViewController(nibName: "RootViewController", bundle: nil)
    let navigationController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    window!.rootViewController = navigationController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

and now you are able to push new view controllers into the hierarchy.

---

## update

if you don't want to show the navigation bar insert this line into the code above.

```
navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

Comment: Yes, but it creates a navigation view in the UI of the app. I do not want that. I want it to move to the other view without showing that navigation view. I did this previously and saw that it created navigation in the UI which I don't want. It should just move to the other view after everything is done in the first view.

Comment: @Rishi, you look smart enough to understand if there is _no_ navigation controller you _cannot_ push anything into it, huhh...? please check my updated answer which shows you how you can remove the navigation bar optionally.

Comment: Thanks. Now, if I want to use that navigationController from viewDidLoad in RootViewController, will it be the same navigationController?

Comment: Actually, I am thought the navigationController is working without even initializing it, so I was confused. I thought its there in UIViewController.

Comment: every view controller's `navigationController` property will be auto-popuplated with the navigation controller instance which directly holds the view controller into its stack.

Comment: But it is still not working. Its not going to the next view. I will edit.

Comment: @Rishi, you _cannot_ push a new view controller into a navigation stack from a view controller which is not already in the stack. the view controller goes to the stack after the `–viewWillAppear:` method, therefore you will be _never_ able to push a new view controller into the stack in the `–viewDidLoad` method. I guess you need to learn a bit more about the view hierarchy. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60618/discussion-between-rishi-and-holex).

Answer (score 0):

```
var next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DashboardController") as! DashboardController
self.presentViewController(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

don't forget to set ViewController `StoryBoard Id` in `StoryBoard` -> `identity inspector`